# How to query a user without specific activities?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

First of all, sorry for the confusing question. I cant quite put my tongue on how I am going to construct it.

In any case, I am trying to answer this query:

> Show the last name, first name, ip address of accounts that did not have an activity of view_exam.

My query as of right now is like this:

```
select a.last_name, a.first_name, b.ip_address 
from account a join access b on a.email = b.email 
where b.activity not like 'view_exam' 
order by date_access desc;
```

I first thought of this as correct. However, once I tried checking the activities done by some of the users, some of them have view_exam. Turns out, I only got a table that does not include activities of view_exam, as shown by one of the user's activities list in the table.
[image] 
How do I query users whose activities list does not include view_exam?

Comment: *My query as of right now is like this:* No. your query selects persons who have at least one activity other than view_exam. It does not check the absence.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.last_name, a.first_name, b.ip_address 
FROM account a 
JOIN access b on a.email = b.email 
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM access с
                   WHERE b.email = c.email
                     AND c.activity = 'view_exam' )
```

Comment: Hi, this works really well. Thank you. Just an additional question, if I were to check the presence of for example view_exam, can I still apply the same 
( SELECT NULL
 FROM access с
 WHERE b.email = c.email
 AND c.activity = 'view_exam' ) but instead of using not exists, I will use exists? Also, If I were to check also the presence of one activity and the absence of another, could separating these two with an AND operator work? Sorry if this was a mouthful.

Comment: @honj-t No. For the presence check your query (with edition `where b.activity = 'view_exam' `) is enough. Maybe it needs in additional DISTINCT.